# Git push submodule on server, pull empty directory

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-push, git-clone

Hi I am pushing my changes using `git push origin production` on to server #1. When I `git clone origin production` on server #2, I get all my files except the sub-module. The sub-module is empty with no `.git` file. I was wondering why this is, and how can I get the files to either #1)`git push` all files to server (this is a third party library) instead of a pointer or #2)be able to `git clone` that empty folder.

```
Server #1:
Root
   -module/
       test/   <--- third party library
          some files

Server #2:
Root
    -module/
        test/  <--- empty
```

Comment: do you have a .gitignore file?

Comment: @HuseyinTUNC yes, it has a .git folder and a .gitignore file. When I delete .gitignore file it says module/test(modified content, untracked content). So I do git rm --cached modules/test, and git add but just keeps giving me untracked

Comment: git add . &&
git commit -m "gitignore removed"  && git push origin production

Comment: can u please try this.

Comment: @HuseyinTUNC When I do git commit, I get `On branch production
Changes not staged for commit: modified:   modules/test (modified content, untracked content)`.  I read about forking, should I think about that instead?

Comment: cd to your projects root path and run 'git add . && git commit -m "gitignore removed" && git push origin production' again

Comment: @HuseyinTUNC Thank you for your help! I have figured out the answer, I will post on the answer board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I have learned more about sub-modules. What ended up happening was I `git push origin production`, but with sub-modules, they don't push the code! Rather, it pushes a link, the link is a pointer to the third party's repo. Here is my set-up:

`root/ 
    .gitmodules`

Server #1: In here I had:

```
[submodule "modules/test"]     <- declaration of submodule
path = modules/test            <- directory 
url = https://git.drupal.org/project/webform.git   <-url
```

Server #2:

When you get pull, you are just pulling the pointer of this sub-module. You have to call `git sub-module init` to initialize it. Then `git sub-module update` which will call the file and clone the directory from the URL you specified in the `.gitmodule` file.

Comment: Wow! I have had that issue for ages. It works! Even if you have some submodules already checked out, this fixes those that are not yet checked out at once.